# Django schedule process to excecute every day at a certain time

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a django app and I want to retrieve some data from remote location and do some processing every day 00.00 H. How to schedule this kind of process to run in the background. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you want is Celery. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/

Comment: Either use celery or cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I use CRON jobs to achieve this, so maybe in a subdirectory called `tasks`, make a file called `processing.py`, and inside write something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/srv/drf-root')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.dev")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.conf import settings
application = get_wsgi_application()

# preprocessing code
```

What this enables you to do, when you run the first bit of this code, you can call models, serializers and other code you have written like you do in the rest of the app, and it's not accessible via API's, thus making it safer from outside influence.

Now you could write a shell script that calls this file, and a bunch of other tasks you have to do, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /srv/drf-root/tasks/preprocess.py
python3 /srv/drf-root/tasks/preprocess_part2.py
```

And then setup CRON to run this task:

```
service crond start
crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 * * * /path/to/shell_script.sh"; } | crontab -
service crond restart
```

Note, the `0 0 * * *` is what gives you your everyday at 00:00 schedule, to get to grips with CRON timing, I suggest you use: `https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*`  [cron-guru-link](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*)

Comment: if you do decide to use `cron` I recommend adding some monitoring and making sure your `ntp` is properly setup. cronitor is a pretty nice service for monitoring fyi..

Comment: Cronitor looks fantastic! I'll be sure to look into that!